# how to link to arrays, so when one item is click will find and display its pair?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm trying to make each logo from the Arr professions display on click certain information from each client. the furthest I have gone is to make each logo display its own logo. IDK if I'm not acceding the properties correctly but I haven't been able to render the information cards

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { imgrep } from "../../Helper/imgrep";
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { CircularProgressbar } from 'react-circular-progressbar';
import 'react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css';


const ShowAndHide = () => {
  const professions = [
    <img class="square" src={imgrep(1)} alt="altofem" />, <img class="round" src={imgrep(2)} alt="vimac" />,
    <img class="square" src={imgrep(3)} alt="peopleparnerts" />, <img class="square" src={imgrep(4)} alt="uplanner" />,
    <img class="square" src={imgrep(5)} alt="vmc" />, <img class="square" src={imgrep(6)} alt="fynsa" />,
    <img class="square" src={imgrep(7)} alt="bolsa" />, <img class="square" src={imgrep(8)} alt="allproperty" />,
    <img class="square" src={imgrep(9)} alt="honorato" />, <img class="square" src={imgrep(10)} alt="trabajando" />,
    <img class="square" src={imgrep(11)} alt="ecosale" />, <img class="square" src={imgrep(12)} alt="unitti" />,
    <img class="square" id="uai" src={imgrep(13)} alt="uai" />
  ];
  const informations = [
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "1", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "2", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "3", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "4", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "5", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "6", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "7", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "8", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "9", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "10", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "11", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "12", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    },
    {
      key: "card", percentage: "13", branch: "", industry: null, resume: null
    }
  ];


  const [myProfession, setMyProfession] = useState("");
  const [information, setMyInformation] = useState("")

  return (
    <>
      {/* INFORMATION CARDS */}
      <Container>
        <LeftSide>
          <Bottom>
            <Edge>

              {myProfession}
            </Edge>

          </Bottom>
        </LeftSide>
        {/* HOVERING LOGOS */}
        <RightSide >
          <h2> - Nuestros Casos de Exito -</h2>
          <br />
          <Buttons>
            {professions.map(profession => (
              <img
                type="img"
                key={profession}
                src={profession.props.src}
                className={profession.props.class}
                id={profession.props.id}
                onClick={() => setMyProfession(profession)}>
              </img>
            ))}
          </Buttons>
        </RightSide>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default ShowAndHide;
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the issue is? So you want the profession images to get rendered on the RightSide and then when an image is clicked what do you want to display on the left side? Just the image of the clicked profession?

Comment: on the left side, I would like to render specific information for each image. for example the growth, the branch they work on, industry, etc So far I have only been able to display the same logos on click.@poku

Comment: You need to link professions and informations together. Ex. giving them an id so when you click a profession you can get the information for that profession by the id. Or merge the two arrays if that is possible.

Comment: great! I'll try to do that. thank you very much  for the speedy answer@poku

Comment: i added an answer with an example. Nicolas Romero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge your datasets together like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { imgrep } from "../../Helper/imgrep";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { CircularProgressbar } from "react-circular-progressbar";
import "react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css";

const ShowAndHide = () => {
  const professions = [
    {
      key: "card",
      percentage: "1",
      branch: "",
      industry: null,
      resume: null,
      logo: <img class="square" src={imgrep(1)} alt="altofem" />
    },
    {
      key: "card",
      percentage: "2",
      branch: "",
      industry: null,
      resume: null,
      logo: <img class="round" src={imgrep(2)} alt="vimac" />
    }
  ];

  const [myProfession, setMyProfession] = useState(undefined);

  return (
    <>
      {/* INFORMATION CARDS */}
      <Container>
        <LeftSide>
          <Bottom>
            {myProfession && (
              <Edge>
                {myProfession.logo}
                {myProfession.branch}
              </Edge>
            )}
          </Bottom>
        </LeftSide>
        {/* HOVERING LOGOS */}
        <RightSide>
          <h2> - Nuestros Casos de Exito -</h2>
          <br />
          <Buttons>
            {professions.map((profession) => (
              <img
                {...profession.logo.props}
                onClick={() => setMyProfession(profession)}
              />
            ))}
          </Buttons>
        </RightSide>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default ShowAndHide;
```

Also i used the spread operator to simplify the  code a bit.